# How to put two clickTags into a standard HTML5 ad banner for DCM (DoubleClick Campaign Manager)?

Tags: javascript, html, banner-ads

Does Anyone know how to put two clickTags into a standard HTML5 ad banner for DCM (DoubleClick Campaign Manager)? Is it even possible? Maybe they only allow one clickTag in the standard banner with DCM?

Comment: Are you using Google Web Designer to create your HTML5 banner?